# How do I configure my topics if want to treat Kafka as a persistent event storage?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic, strimzi

We're using Apache Kafka together with Strimzi on Kubernetes. If we want to treat Kafka as a persistent event storage (keeping events indefinitely) how would I have to configure my Topics?

Is my assumption correct, that if we leave the default cleanup.policy (delete) and retention.bytes (-1) and set retention.ms to -1 that the events are never deleted?

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaTopic
metadata:
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-kafka-cluster
  name: my-topic
spec:
  config:
    # cleanup.policy: delete -> default
    # retention.bytes: -1 -> default 
    retention.ms: -1
  partitions: 3
  replicas: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. If you read the [Apache documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) on these settings, you can see that `retention.bytes` and `retention.ms` are dependent on using the `delete` cleanup policy. Leaving `retention.bytes` at the default (meaning there's no size limit just a time limit) means that `retention.ms` determines the time events are retained, and you have set that time to none.